# How can I access the value in a named capture group in a regex in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to access the captured data that was captured in a named capture group called as a subroutine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
"this is a test" =~ /(?!)
(?<isa>is\s+a)
| (?&isa)\s
(?<test>test)/x;
print "isa: $+{isa}\ntest: $+{test}"
```

And here's another attempt:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
"this is a test" =~ /(?!)
(?<isa_>(?<isa>is\s+a))
| (?&isa_)\s
(?<test>test)/x;
print "isa: $+{isa}\ntest: $+{test}"
```

I can't seem to get $+{isa} to be populated.  Why is that and how do I do so?

Comment: Please don't "fix" your question to remove errors indicated in answers or comments, as it makes nonsense out of them. You are free to *add* as much code as you wish

Comment: @Borodin, the question's original intent was compromised, distracting from it and the answer. The answer should be fixed, not the question.

Comment: I disagree. It would have been better to have added corrected code to your question instead of just rolling it back. But please at least edit the answer if you feel it needs fixing. At present your question doesn't match the answer, which is the worst of both worlds.

Comment: @Borodin, fine. I figured that was the responsibility of the poster of the answer, but I have now corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you force the first branch to fail with `(?!)`, the named capture group `(?<isa>...)` that is defined after doesn't capture anything (but is defined as a subpattern).

Only the second branch succeeds, but this one doesn't capture anything for the group "isa", it only uses the subpattern alias `(?&isa_)`.

Your first example returns the warning:

```
Reference to nonexistent named group in regex
```

since "isa_" is defined nowhere.

[EDIT] you have changed your "isa_" to "isa" in your first example, but with this new version, there's no reason anything will be captured in the "isa" named group.

Your second example will not populate "isa" too, because the capture groups captures things only where they are defined, not elsewhere (even if `isa_` refers to the group `isa`.)

The reason is that Perl doesn't store captures in a recursion *(only captures at the ground level are kept)*. You can test it with this example:

```
"this is a test" =~ /
  (?!)
  (?<isa_>
      (?<isa> is \s+ a)
      (?{print "isa in recursion: $+{isa}\n"})
  )
|
  (?&isa_) \s (?<test> test )
/x;

print "isa: $+{isa}\ntest: $+{test}"
```

---

However, you can write:

```
"this is a test" =~ /
  (?!) (?<isa_> is \s+ a )
|
  (?<isa> (?&isa_) ) \s (?<test> test )
/x;

print "isa: $+{isa}\ntest: $+{test}";
```

But here, the named capture "isa" is at the ground level.

---

Note: instead of using `(?!)` to make the pattern fail and an alternation, you can use the `(?(DEFINE)...)` syntax:

```
/(?(DEFINE)
     (?<isa_> (?<isa> is \s+ a) )
 )
 (?&isa_) \s (?<test> test )
/x
```

or this one:

```
/(?<isa_> (?<isa> is \s+ a) ){0}
 (?&isa_) \s (?<test> test )
/x
```

In this way you avoid the cost of an alternation.

Comment: So then, is it possible to access a named capture group in a subroutine?

Comment: Oops. Yeah, the first code was a copy error. Corrected in the question. I also just found out about the `(?(DEFINE)...)` syntax last week.  I've been using the `(?!)...|` syntax for a couple of years now.  Just never noticed that perl didn't capture anything above the ground level before because I used `(?{...})` instead.  I've also used `...(*ACCEPT)|(?!)(_subroutines_)`.