# How to get a group matched in a recursive regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-recursion

I'm writing a simple regular expression that needs receive a pair of coordinates and/or a map name.

For example:

```
move 10 15 # should returns [[10, 15]]
move 10 15 map # should returns [[10, 15, 'map']]
move map # should returns [['map']]
move 10 15 mapA mapB # should returns [[10, 15, 'mapA'], ['mapB']] 
move 10 15 mapA mapB 33 44 # should returns [[10, 15, 'mapA'], ['mapB'], [33, 44]]
move 10 15 mapA 33 44 mapB # should returns [[10, 15, 'mapA'], [33, 44, 'mapB']]
```

Then, I wrote this regular expression:

```
/
  (?(DEFINE)
     (?<coord>    (?<x>\d+)\s+(?<y>\d+) )
     (?<map>      (?<mapname>[a-zA-Z]+) )
     (?<commands> \s* (?: (?&coord) | (?&map) ) \s* (?&commands)? )
  )
  move\s+(?&commands)
/six
```

But how I can get the value for groups `x`, `y` and `map` using Perl?

I tried with some ways:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $command = 'move 10 15';

$command =~ /
  (?(DEFINE)
     (?<coord>    (?<x>\d+)\s+(?<y>\d+) )
     (?<map>      (?<mapname>[a-zA-Z]+) )
     (?<commands> \s* (?: (?&coord) | (?&map) ) \s* (?&commands)? )
  )
  move\s+(?&commands)
/six;

while (my ($k,$v) = each %+) { print "$k $v\n" }
print "$+{x}";
```

Comment: So your regex works properly and you just need to access the groups?

Comment: @revo Yeah. As far I tested, my regex works, but I don't know how to access the groups

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369803/how-can-i-access-the-value-in-a-named-capture-group-in-a-regex-in-perl

Comment: @revo I tried using it, but I can't. `%+` returns nothing.

Comment: Please show your attempt in your question.

Comment: @Jan Sorry. I updated the code renaming the second `map` for `mapname`. But I still have the same problem

Comment: See also [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars)

Comment: [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2) might be worth considering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the question stands, you can't have that.  The [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) says about this

> Note that capture groups matched inside of recursion are not accessible after the recursion returns, so the extra layer of capturing groups is necessary.

but the pattern `<x>` can't be had with "an extra layer" of capturing afterwards since it's used only inside the grammar.  You can only have the whole thing

```
if ($command =~ /
        move\s+ (?<match>(?&commands))
        (?(DEFINE)
            (?<coord>    (?<x>\d+)\s+(?<y>\d+) )
            (?<map>      (?<mapname>[a-zA-Z]+) )
            (?<commands> \s* (?: (?&coord) | (?&map) ) \s* (?&commands)? )
        )
    /six)
{
    say "got: $+{match}";
}
```

where I've moved the `?(DEFINED)` block at the end of the pattern, as recommended.

Note that it wouldn't make sense either: in a recursive match, *which* of multiple `<x>` should one get? So you'd need to restructure the approach so to be able to re-capture the match you want; but I don't see how to do this if you want a subpattern buried so deeply.

For the problem as presented I'd go with writing a simple parser, never mind a catch-all regex. Or, in your approach re-process the match for its parts, hopefully much easier once you have it.

And then there are powerful tools, like [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2), [Parse::RecDescent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RecDescent), [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars).

Comment: Very thank you for the good answer! I'm doing it just for study purpose (and "insistence"), to compare the limits between regex and a simple parser.
In my real project, I'm using parser combinator to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is better to divide and conquer than to force feed everything into one regex?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @row;
    chomp;
    if (/^move/) {
        while (/(?:(\d+)\s+(\d+))?(?:\s+([[:alpha:]]+))?/g) {
            my @match;
            push(@match, +$1, +$2) if $1 && $2;
            push(@match, $3)       if $3;
            push(@row, \@match) if @match;
        }
    }

    print "$_: ", Dumper(\@row);
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
move 10 15
move 10 15 map
move map
move 10 15 mapA mapB
move 10 15 mapA mapB 33 44
move 10 15 mapA 33 44 mapB
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
move 10 15: $VAR1 = [
          [
            '10',
            '15'
          ]
        ];
move 10 15 map: $VAR1 = [
          [
            '10',
            '15',
            'map'
          ]
        ];
move map: $VAR1 = [
          [
            'map'
          ]
        ];
move 10 15 mapA mapB: $VAR1 = [
          [
            '10',
            '15',
            'mapA'
          ],
          [
            'mapB'
          ]
        ];
move 10 15 mapA mapB 33 44: $VAR1 = [
          [
            '10',
            '15',
            'mapA'
          ],
          [
            'mapB'
          ],
          [
            '33',
            '44'
          ]
        ];
move 10 15 mapA 33 44 mapB: $VAR1 = [
          [
            '10',
            '15',
            'mapA'
          ],
          [
            '33',
            '44',
            'mapB'
          ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I cannot yet comment, Stefan Becker's solution has a flaw.

It will fail if a coordinate is 0.

Here's the fix:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @row;
    chomp;
    if (/^move/) {
        while (/(?:(\d+)\s+(\d+))?(?:\s+([[:alpha:]]+))?/g) {
            my @match;
            push(@match, +$1, +$2) if defined $1 && defined $2;
            push(@match, $3)       if $3;
            push(@row, \@match) if @match;
        }
    }

    print "$_: ", Dumper(\@row);
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
move 10 15
move 10 15 map
move map
move 10 15 mapA mapB
move 10 15 mapA mapB 33 44
move 10 15 mapA 33 44 mapB
move 0 15 mapA 33 44 mapB
```